Default selection of a radio button in HTML
I have a datatable in my asp.net core mvc application and there is a 3 radio button inside one header column for filtering column data in the datatable. But when the page loads, the ALL labeled radio option should be selected by default. How can it be achieved?
I have tried this.
                '<div>' +
                 '<label>Is Active ? </label><br>' +
                 '<input type="radio" name="foo" id="filter-active" /> Active<br>' +
                 '<input type="radio" name="foo" id="filter-non-active" /> Non Active<br>' +
                 '<input type="radio" name="foo" id="filter-all" value="" checked /> ALL' +
                '</div>'

But it shows only like this:


The entire point of a radio control is that only one can be selected at a time (from the linked MDN page: "Only one radio button in a given group can be selected at the same time."). If you need to support multiple option selections, you've selected the entirely wrong interface element and instead should look to <input type="checkbox">.

@esqew I don't want a multiple selection at a time. If we use checkbox, we can select or click multiple values. That I don't want. I need to select 1 option at a time. Thanks

How do you square your statement "I need to select 1 option at a time" with the one from your question "ALL option should be selected"? These are directly contradictory with one another - both cannot be true simultaneously.

The HTML you have should work fine. First step would be to make sure that the HTML is being output correctly by going to "view source." Second step would be to make sure some JavaScript isn't changing the page state when the page loads.

@esqew There is a ALL labeled radio button here. When selecting that radio button, it will fetch all the Active and Non Active data from database into the datatable. When ALL radio option is selected, other 2 radio buttons will be unselected.

The HTML you have should work fine.
The first debugging step would be to make sure that the HTML is being output correctly by going to "view source."
A second step would be to make sure some JavaScript isn't changing the page state when the page loads.
Highlander Radio Buttons: There Can Only Be One
I'm guessing that because your form controls are in a table, you're outputting multiples of them. This can lead to complications.
HTML is kind of tricky in that if you have a radio button with the same name attribute more than once in a form, only one can be checked at one time.
Put them under different <form> elements to make it work as-expected.


<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="one" /> One</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="two" checked /> Two</label>

<p>... later in the form ...</p>

<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="abcd" checked /> ABCD</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="defg" /> DEFG</label>



If you do have multiple radio inputs with the same name, they'll need to be in a different <form> to work as expected.


<form>
<div>
 Is Active ? <br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="one" /> One</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="two" checked /> Two</label>
</div>
</form>

<p>... later in the page, inside a different &lt;form&gt; ...</p>

<form>
<div>
 Is Active ? <br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="abcd" checked /> ABCD</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="defg" /> DEFG</label>
</div>
</form>



Other Considerations
Your code isn't using <label> correctly. Apart from not being accessibility-friendly, I can't click the text label and activate the control, which I personally find annoying. Fix this by restructuring as <label><input>Text</label>.


<div>
 Is Active ?<br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="foo" id="filter-active" /> Active</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="foo" id="filter-non-active" /> Non Active</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="foo" id="filter-all" value="" checked /> ALL</label>
</div>




I'm sorry, but this doesn't solve the issue being that among a radio group with each radio input having the same name but a different id and value, it is impossible to default check one of these radio inputs.
I have to add that I also have this issue right now and it only occurs on Chrome and not Mozilla. So this sounds more like a bug from Chrome rather than the code of the author of this topic being wrong.

@Sunamin34 it is impossible to default check one of these radio inputs -- that's not OP's issue, read the question again.

Set aside the labelling issue, and the fact that the separate groups of radio inputs should be grouped by a common "name" attribute but yet distinct for each radio group
the ALL labeled radio option should be selected by default. How can it be achieved?.
He did use a "checked" attribute for the radio input with the value set to "". This should already work, preselecting its "ALL" radio input. I invite the OP to try opening its app on Mozilla and he'll realise that it will work. It's a Chrome issue.

@Sunamin34 Oh, I understand now what you're saying. I'm not convinced your issue is the same as OP's issue. To reproduce, I modified my snippets above to include a checked attribute and tested on Chrome 123.0, and it worked as expected. Can you try my snippets in your Chrome?
